# Shannon's Entropy, manual vs. analytic results differ

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Let's say that I have information string A, B, C, D, E.

All letters are equally probable (1/5). So Shannon's formula would give us.

```
# Original Formula
sum(p * log(1/p,2))

# Which can be simplified in this case as
0.2*log(5,2)*5 = 2.321928
```

However, if I manually try to count the number of bits that have to asked, I come up with 2.4.

```
             ABCDE
           /      \
        ABC        DE
       /   \      /  \
     AB     C    D    E
    /   \   
   A     B
```

2 letters require 3 questions and 3 letters require 2 questions. This means that the average number of questions should be (3+3+2+2+2)/5 = 2.4

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am assuming it is because in my manual breakdown theu are not true 50-50 probability splits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shannon entropy gives you a limit on what you could achieve by lossless compressing the data. You can't do better than that, but it's not easy (and maybe not guaranteed) to achieve that limit as well. Your way of doing the compression resembles very much *[Huffman Coding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Huffman_coding)*, which is *optimal* in the sense that each symbol is associated with a bit string. However, you could have tried to code pairs of symbols, i.e. $AA,AB,...$ and achieve a different bit length; or you may continue to do so as well by considering triples, quadruples etc. The algorithm to converge Shannon entropy may not reveal itself at all. Your coding will reach Shannon entropy limit if the alphabet size is $2^k$, with equiprobable symbols; which is in line with your comment that your splits are not true 50-50 splits.